# Como fazer mascara monetária no Edit Text Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, edittext, valor-monetário

Bom dia senhores, estou com dificuldades em colocar uma mascara monetária em um Edit Text, verifiquei diversos fóruns e tutoriais porém nenhum método funcionou. O meu projeto é fazer basicamente o cliente colocar o valor do produto no Edit Text, isso já está funcionando, porém eu gostaria de colocar uma máscara, poderiam me ajudar ?

```
public class Tecladonumerico extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button botao1;
    public Button botao2;
    public Button botao3;
    public Button botao4;
    public Button botao5;
    public Button botao6;
    public Button botao7;
    public Button botao8;
    public Button botao9;
    public Button botao0;
    public Button botaoX;
    public Button botaoC;
    public Button botaoA;
    public EditText valor;

    Boolean bool = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.layoutcores );
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setGravity( Gravity.TOP );
        getWindow().setLayout( (int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .8) );


//AQUI ESTÁ A VÁRIAVEL QUE CHAMA OS DADOS DO EDIT TEXT
        valor = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.calcula);

        botao1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        botao2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        botao3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        botao4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        botao5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        botao6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        botao7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        botao8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        botao9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        botao0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        botaoA= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttona);
        botaoX = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonx);
        botaoC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonc);


    }



    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void Botao1(View view){
        if (bool == false){

            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "1");
        }
    }

    public void Botao2(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "2");
        }
    }

    public void Botao3(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "3");
        }
    }

    public void Botao4(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "4");
        }
    }

    public void Botao5(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "5");
        }
    }

    public void Botao6(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "6");
        }
    }

    public void Botao7(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "7");
        }
    }

    public void Botao8(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "8");
        }
    }

    public void Botao9(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "9");
        }
    }

    public void Botao0(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText(str + "0");
        }
    }

    public void BotaoC(View view){
        if (bool == false){
            String str = valor.getText().toString();
            valor.setText("");
        }
    }

    public void BotaoA(View view){
        String str = valor.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("KEY", str);
        this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        this.finish();
    }

    public void botaoX(View v){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: O que seria esse valor.setText(str + "1")... não entendi isso. Eu possuo uma máscara aqui que deixa o formato dos números do Edittext de acordo com o local da pessoa. exemplo 1000 no Br fica 1.000,00 no EUA 1,000.00 em alguns países Europeus 1 000,00

Comment: esse (str+"1") ele permite que eu possa colocar o número "1" quantas vezes eu quiser no campo de valor, por exemplo: se eu preencher uma vez o valor do str será "1", então eu irei preencher outra vez com o mesmo valor e ele se tornará "11" e assim por diante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie a seguinte classe:

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;
    private final Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(editText);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        BigDecimal parsed = parseToBigDecimal(editable.toString());
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed);
        //Remove o símbolo da moeda e espaçamento pra evitar bug
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s\\s]", getCurrencySymbol());
        String cleanString = formatted.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        editText.setText(cleanString);
        editText.setSelection(cleanString.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private BigDecimal parseToBigDecimal(String value) {
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", getCurrencySymbol());

        String cleanString = value.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        try {
            return new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(
                    2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //ao apagar todos valores de uma só vez dava erro
            //Com a exception o valor retornado é 0.00
            return new BigDecimal(0);

        }
    }

    public static String formatPrice(String price) {
        //Ex - price = 2222
        //retorno = 2222.00
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        return String.valueOf(df.format(Double.valueOf(price)));

    }

    public static String formatTextPrice(String price) {
        //Ex - price = 3333.30
        //retorna formato monetário em Br = 3.333,30
        //retorna formato monetário EUA: 3,333.30
        //retornar formato monetário de alguns países europeu: 3 333,30
        BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(formatPriceSave(formatPrice(price)));
        String newFormat = String.valueOf(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(bD));
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s]", getCurrencySymbol());
        return newFormat.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

    }

    static String formatPriceSave(String price) {
        //Ex - price = $ 5555555
        //return = 55555.55 para salvar no banco de dados
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", getCurrencySymbol());
        String cleanString = price.replaceAll(replaceable, "");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(cleanString.replaceAll(" ", ""));

        return String.valueOf(stringBuilder.insert(cleanString.length() - 2, '.'));

    }

    public static String getCurrencySymbol() {
        return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault()).getCurrency().getSymbol();

    }
}
```

Dentro do onCreate da sua Activity e dpois de incializar o editText, acrescente:

```
valor.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(valor));
```

**Opção:**
No seu BotãoA que envia essa String do EditText lembre-se que estará enviando um valor dependendo da configuração do aparelho do usuário. o Valor "1000", se estiver em Pt-Br será 1.000,00 em EUA 1,000.00 em alguns países da Europa 1 000,00, se quiser enviar como valor padrão "1000.00" pra um database deixe no BotãoA:

```
String str = formatPriceSave(valor.getText().toString());
```

caso precise recuperar esse valor depois e transformar em monetário novamente pode recuperar ele normal e usar o método formatTextPrice que irá transformar 1000.00 para o padrão monetario que o aparelho está configurado.

Comment: Utilizo essa mascará a um bom tempo, nunca tive problemas. Vi um exemplo dela um tempo atrás, e alterei para oque eu precisava. E testei aqui pro seu exemplo e funcionou bem.